# Make a wireframe out of an uneven rectangle with even thickness?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

Hey I'm a newbie to blender and I want to model rooms of a building. The rooms should be wireframes except the floor, which can be a simple face. But when I use the Wireframe modifier on rooms that are not perfect squares it looks uneven in thickness. Is there a way to make everything the same thickness and keep it editable in case I want it thicker or thinner in the future? Here is a picture to describe my problem:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have scaled your object in *Object* mode, so it's not scaled 1/1/1 on the XYZ axis anymore, you just need to apply your scale in *Object* mode: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*